# Less inherit exact attributes for hover and focus

Tags: less

I have a less file with this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background: @dark-bg;
    margin-top: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 23px 4px #333;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 23px 4px #333;
    box-shadow:         0px -3px 23px 4px #333;

}
```

I would like to do something like so:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a {
     background: @dark-bg;
     margin-top: 2px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 23px 4px #333;
     -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 23px 4px #333;
     box-shadow:         0px -3px 23px 4px #333;
     &:hover, &:focus {
         // some command to inherit all the attributes without repeating myself
   }
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to directly inherit everything instead of repeating myself like this. Is this possible with LESS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, just reuse the `&` selector once more:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a {
    &,
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        background: @dark-bg;
        margin-top: 2px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 23px 4px #333;
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 23px 4px #333;
        box-shadow:         0px -3px 23px 4px #333;
    }
}
```

The `&` characters gets replaced with the literal value of the wrapping selector.

Comment: yay! thank you! (I can't accept the answer for the next 10 minutes, so... uh... wait I guess)

Comment: @yuvi, no problem. I should note, however, that your selector appears to have an unnecessarily high specificity. I'd recommend simplifying as much as possible. Maintaining a long selector like that will get you into specificity wars with yourself when you eventually need to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm actually creating my own bootstrap theme, so this is simply over-riding their definitions. Also, can I limit the `&` for only the first child?

Comment: @yuvi, that makes a lot of sense. Bootstrap's styles aren't architected in a maintainable way. As for your question, it sounds like you need `&:first-child`, but I don't really understand what you're asking enough to give you good advice on it. Just remember that LESS *is* CSS in the end, so if you know what you want the CSS to look like, you can always go backwards to make it simpler in LESS.

Comment: Yeah it's kinda messy. Thanks for the tips, I'll keep those in mind.